# Django-dbbackup: how to change backup file extension?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am trying to use [django-dbbackup](http://django-dbbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commands.html#dbbackup) module to backup my database. After running `dbbackup` it saves a db dump with a name something like this:

```
default-user-2018-03-22-220805.psql
```

Then I delete 1 last row in one tables of my db. Next I run `dbrestore` and get the follow:

```
> Finding latest backup Restoring backup for database 'default' and
> server 'None' 
> Restoring: default-user-2018-03-22-220805.psql
> Restore tempfile created: 407.0 KiB 
> Are you sure you want to continue?
> [Y/n]  y
> Following files were affected
```

But after that - nothing happens. The deleted row is not restored in my db.
I have read some where (unfortunately already lost that page) that to restore my db the dump file must be in `.tar` format.
 Also I have tried to use that `.psql` with `pgAdmin 4` - to restore db via UI tool. But got an error that input file is not a valid archive.
 And last I tried to use that file with Windows cmd running `pd_restore` and got:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive
```

> So the question is: how to use django-dbbackup `dbrestore` with its
>   generated file or how to change the extension format of its output
>   files if it is not possible to restore from `.psql` files?

P.S. I have also found in the source code a row `extension = 'psql'`, tried to change that, and it worked - I got a `.tar` file on the output but next `dbrestore` said that:

```
Finding latest backup
CommandError: There's no backup file available.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change file backup extension with this variable

```
DBBACKUP_FILENAME_TEMPLATE = '{databasename}-{servername}-{datetime}.sql'
```

You define DBBACKUP_FILENAME_TEMPLATE variable in settings.py

This setting change extension backup file from dump to sql.
You can change sql extension file with another extension.